# Magento 242 bin/magento deploy:mode:set production deploy all languages

Tags: magento2, deploy

Whenever i run command `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`, it always auto deploy all languages, takes a long time, makes high CPU and RAM usages.

I would like it to generate files for `en_US` instead
How do i achieve this?

I used `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US`, it is fine but Magento App does not switch to `production` mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have set your locale in Stores > Settings > Configuration > General.
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/locale-options.html

Magento should only deploy the locale you have set for your store, and also the locale for your admin users, if different. You can set Admin user locale by clicking username in top right corner.
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/admin-account.html

Comment: Thank @bernieu2. I just realized that my shop has too many website and languages. Every time i run deploy without parameter or run deploy:mode:set production, the system auto deploy all lang

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command:

```
bin/Magento deploy:mode:set production -s
```

where:
-s (--skip-compilation) is an optional parameter you can use to skip code compilation when you change to production mode.
For more [see here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html)

Comment: thank you @Arunendra